# Задача Иосифа Флавия  с помощью циклического списка

Tags: c++, списки

[Связные списки в С++](http://andrei-sapeshko.blogspot.ru/2013/04/blog-post.html) - 
тут есть пример, но он немного непонятный.

```
struct node
{
  int item;
  node *next;

  node(int x, node *t)
  {
    item = x;
    next = t;
  }
};
```

Comment: @pmipmi, сама программка-то (по Вашей ссылке) абсолютно прозрачна, но вот в чем суть **задачи Иосифа Флавия** (что нужно сделать?) я тоже не понял.

Вообще же, если говорить о циклическом списке, как структуре данных, то лучше делать его двусвязным.

Comment: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/joseph_problem здесь решения. но нужен список.

Comment: @pmipmi, так в чём проблема-то? Что конкретно непонятно?

Answer (score 2):

[[@pmipmi](/users/14317/pmipmi)](/users/14317/pmipmi), если взять код [andrei.sapeshko](http://andrei-sapeshko.blogspot.ru/2013/04/blog-post.html), на который Вы ссылаетесь, то очевидно номера убиваемых можно печатать в

```
while(x != x->next)
{
  for (i = 1; i < M; i++)
  {
    x = x->next;
  }
  cout << x->next->item << '\n';
  x->next = x->next->next;
}
```

а решение задачи (по Вашей второй ссылке это оставшийся) в самом конце

```
cout << "Last alive: " << x->item << '\n';
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Предположи, что N=9 M=5, где каждый раз в цикле

```
for (i = 1; i < M; i++)
```

берем M-ный элемент, а затем его удаляем

```
x->next = x->next->next
```

порядок удаления элементов будет - 5, 1, 7, 4, 3, 6, 9, 2, а 8 останется.